# Is it possible to get from France to England and from Denmark to Sweden human powered?

Tags: france, bicycles, sweden, england, denmark

For a project of mine, I would like to cycle from France to England and from Denmark to Sweden.

In case of France to England I think it is definitively not possible to cycle through the tunnel. But are there any other feasible ways for an averaged-trained person with no special skills to cross the sea there by human power only? Swimming for example is not an option, since it would need superior skills and stamina.

In case of Denmark to Sweden, it's definitively possible. In the worst case, one would need to travel all the way through Russia, but it's doable. But there is also the Oresund bridge. Can I cycle there? If not, maybe walk?

Comment: Swimming does indeed require training and support but for administrative reasons it's currently not possible from France to England, only in the other direction.

Comment: You can also canoe.

Comment: And fly:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gossamer_Albatross

Comment: It's not possible to cycle through the tunnel, [unless you're Chris Froome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VeOeZxWiryM). In that case, [it's no problem...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wwcjpg9lL4g)

Comment: Does sailing count, or is that cheating?

Comment: @Relaxed Not _legal_ and not _possible_ are two quite different things. :)

Comment: @reirab Maybe but that's not my point, I haven't even used the word “legal”. Realistically, if you want to attempt it without dying in the process, you need quite a lot of help (a kayak, a boat, and people who know about tides and currents to time your attempt properly). The main group you can turn for that would be the Channel Swimming Association and its registered pilots, who only support crossings in one direction.

Comment: Of course, if you are completely crazy and want to swim with no support at all or so rich you buy a boat and arrange a crew yourself, you might theoretically be able to try in the other direction but then we are talking about a movie plot, not actual travel.

Comment: @Relaxed Not just tides and currents; you also have to navigate around large, fast-moving container ships, ferries, and all the other traffic in the Channel, of which there is a lot. And, no, that container ship cannot stop for a swimmer; it can't break the laws of physics.

Comment: @Relaxed Ah, my bad. I thought by "administrative reasons," you meant immigration laws or something of the like.

Comment: Note that if you want to go the long way around the Baltic Sea, the feasibility of that depends on where in Denmark you start out. If your origin is Copenhagen, getting across the Storebælt fixed link will pose very similar problems to crossing the Øresund: There's a fixed link, but it's motorway and railway only.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh thanks for the hint, I would not have thought about that

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, there is quite a lot of traffic but to be honest I am not sure exactly how they deal with it. AFAIK, the timing is based on tides and currents, as there are ships going in all directions at all times.

Comment: @Relaxed The English Channel uses a [traffic separation scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_Separation_Scheme) where there are literally lanes of traffic, and the support crew is there in part to guide you through the traffic.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I also know that but that hardly explains how they deal with large ships as swimmers (and ferries) cross the TSC. In any case, my point is that it's not what departure timing is about.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends on what you consider 'special skills'. With some excercise, paddling should be feasible for most people.

For the English Channel, you can easily find operators and boat charterers offering planning support or equipment rent: http://www.fullthrottleboatcharters.com/kayak-across-english-channel/

Crossing the Øresund may not be much more than 5km (depending on where you cross) and can obviously be done with very simple equipment. Here's a video of two Swedes crossing on stand up paddleboards: https://vimeo.com/102203607

Comment: What's Øresund ?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid The strait between Zealand and the Swedish mainland.

Answer (score 10):

As of July 2014, bicycles were not allowed on the Øresund Bridge.  [Check back in 55 years:](http://www.thelocal.se/20140701/sweden-proposes-new-bike-path-to-copenhagen)

> It's currently forbidden to cycle across the Öresund bridge, a part-bridge, part-tunnel connection between Malmö and Copenhagen, which was made famous by the hit television show The Bridge. But if new proposals by Sweden-based construction company Skanska and Swedish consultancy firm Sweco come into effect, the dream for commuting cyclists could become a reality.
>
> ...
>
> The bike lane, referred to as a "super cycle path" (supercykelväg), would run in separate tunnel above the cars on the Öresund Bridge.
>
> ...
>
> A report from the two companies explained that growth is expected to skyrocket in the Öresund area, meaning an increase of an estimated one million people by the year 2070.